# How can I do a Google site search with a partial URL?

Tags: google-search

I'm trying to set up a site search query for the Python 3.6 library reference page here:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/index.html

I tried the following query:

```
site:docs.python.org/3 string
```

I get some relevant looking results, but it's not quite narrowed down enough. Using `site:docs.python.org/3.6/library` doesn't work at all.

Basically I want search results to match this wildcard pattern:

```
docs.python.org/3.6/library/*
```

How can I get this to work with Google search?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps something like

```
site:docs.python.org inurl:3.6/library
```

That should limit results to being in the `docs.python.org` domain for pages with "3.6/library" somewhere in the URL.

Comment: Although, looking at what I'm getting back, I'm wondering if that part of their site is properly indexed by Google. I think they, either intentionally or by accident, are keeping Google from indexing that part of the site. Testing on other similar sorts of sites I'm getting good results.

Comment: Looking more, I see `<link rel="canonical" href="https://docs.python.org/3/library/index.html" />` in their HTML source. That means they want the URLs to not contain the `.6`. This works great, though: `site:docs.python.org inurl:3/library string`.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but sadly this means I get duplicate results across multiple 3.x versions of Python: Same result for python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 for example. Was wanting to narrow it down to a specific version.